# How different components in QT framework intereact?

Tags: qt, qt5, desktop

I am self-learning how to code and trying to develop a small desktop application. I choose QT as a framework for this. I didn't understand the following code. There is no relation between the 'app' and 'button' objects. How the 'button' object is part of the 'app' event loop.

```
    #include <QApplication>
    #include <QPushButton>

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
         QApplication app (argc, argv);

         QPushButton button ("Hello world !");
         button.show();

         return app.exec();
    }
```

Comment: Do you understand what an eventloop is?

Comment: @eyllanesc  I am thinking that the program control is in a loop waiting for the events to occur. Based on the events, it triggers certain actions to take place.

Comment: Well then, that's the answer: The event loop is notified of events that it handles (for example, the click) through signals, and the eventloop invokes the slot associated with that signal.

Comment: But how the app.exec() knows about the presence of button. Aren't the app and button two separate things defined in two separate variables?

Comment: They are 2 separate variables that interact, QApplication handles the QWidget tree (like QPushButton) since not only the QWidget sends information to the eventloop but the eventloop also sends information to it. For example when you click on the button you actually click on the window, then the OS notifies that to the eventloop, and the eventloop according to some logic analyzes which widgets are affected and sends the event to it.